# Laravel routing, redirect with parameters

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm aware there are similar questions, but the answers provided there do not work for me.

I had the following URL in my Laravel application:

http://example.com/anatomy/18917/why-cant-i-bend-my-back

Now the "anatomy" section has been renamed to "physio" and the new URL for the same content is this:

http://example.com/physio/18917/why-cant-i-bend-my-back

It's a GET route with the format `physio/{id}/{slug}`

Now, I would like to provide backwards compatibility (for any users that may have bookmarked an article in the old URL format).

So I am trying to redirect, for example, `anatomy/18917/why-cant-i-bend-my-back` to `physio/18917/why-cant-i-bend-my-back`. I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
$router->get('anatomy/{id}/{slug}', function() {
    return redirect()->to('physio', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
});
```

And the error I get is `undefined variable: id`. If I do the following it redirects correctly to the homepage, but I would rather redirect to the actual article with the given parameters.

```
$router->get('anatomy/{id}/{slug}', function() {
    return redirect()->to('/');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$router->get('anatomy/{id}/{slug}', function() {
    return redirect()->to('physio', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
});
```

to

```
$router->get('anatomy/{id}/{slug}', function($id,$slug) {
    return redirect()->to('physio', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
});
```

You nedd to pass `$id` and `$slug` in function

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#redirect-routes)

Comment: When I do that I get `The HTTP status code "1" is not valid`.

Comment: Set route name of `physio/id/slug` route. your new route. Then use `return redirect()->route('routename', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug])`

Comment: I think if @jovan can give name to the old route then you can use `redirect()->route(...)` otherwise you can save yourself the time by constructing the url by yourself. That is, `redirect()->to("pysio/$id/$slug")` //take note of the double quote

Comment: Yes @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Answer (score 0):

**inside the controller**

```
function($id,$slug) {
    return redirect()->to('physio', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
};
```